# Determine the speed of a solenoid

Tags: solenoid

I've found [this](http://www.conrad.de/ce/de/product/502261/Zylindermagnet-Intertec-ITS-LZ-2560-D-12VDC-12-VDC-Befestigung-Schraubgewinde-Ausfuehrung-drueckend-Anfangs-Endkraft-07/?ref=detview1&rt=detview1&rb=1) solenoid online.
In my current project I try to generate fake recoil for a lasertag marker.

Now my question is:

**Can I determine the time the solenoid needs for completing one cycle?**

One cycle means powering the solenoid until full length (18mm) is reached and then snapping back in its original state. Basically I need to know if i can complete the cycle in under 70ms.

Comment: ... apparently, not from the datasheet.

Comment: It'll depend on the mass you're trying to move but because the force also varies along the length of travel it may be a bit tricky to estimate accurately. Personally I'd just try it with a few different masses and see what feels natural, without anything attached I'd be surprised if you can't do it in 70 ms but then of course you won't get much recoil.

Comment: It is exactly 1G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My German is not so good.  But you could try a simple mechanics estimate.
So take a force of 10N and a plunger mass (guess) of 100g = 0.1kg, that's an acceleration of 100 m/s^2.  Then distance = 1/2 a*t^2, (distance one way is about 0.02m)  I get 20 ms for one way. (It will be longer than that because the force decreases with distance.)  I'd just buy one and play with it.